# Is there a true, "before" hook in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

I've read through the documentation but I can't find like a true, "before" hook.

In WebdriverIO we have access to the before hook in the wdio.config.ts file to set up anything that needs to only be set up once (Axios connections, database connections, etc...).

I implemented a singleton pattern so that I only have to set them up once for each test suite run.

wdio.config.ts:

```
before: async function (): Promise<void> {
    webServiceA.setupClient();
    webServiceB.setupClient();
    webServiceC.setupClient();
    webServiceD.setupClient();
    webServiceE.setupClient();
    webServiceF.setupClient();
    webServiceG.setupClient();
    webServiceH.setupClient();
},
```

I set up a bunch of backend webservice clients that my test will need for test data generation.    I only have to instantiate once in the wdio.config.ts file, not in any spec file.  How can I achieve this with Playwright?

Comment: [`beforeAll`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-all-1), [`beforeEach`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-each-1)?

Comment: @ggorlen those are great to use in a spec file but I needed something that truly is only called once for the entire run and would be good across multiple spec files.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at using [Global setup / project dependencies](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown) for this which is setup in playwright.config.ts - similar to what you mention in wdio.config.ts

I use this method to have a setup project which runs before everything which I use to scaffold our AUT with data using the API.